# After Discord.js v13 update, unable to catch errors with error event

Tags: discord.js

A while ago, I updated to discord.js v13. I had a simple error catching function for my bot, and it's always worked.

```
obs.on('error', err => {
console.log(err); });
```

After updating and changing a few things like embeds, I realized that I can no longer catch errors. In fact, if I try to purposely do a bad command, such as making the bot send an empty message, discord always return a full error

```
C:\Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414
if (!allowEmpty && data.length === 0) throw new error(errorMessage);
RangeError [MESSAGE_CONTENT_TYPE]: Message content must be a non-empty string.
at Function.verifyString (C:\Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:414:49)
at MessagePayload.makeContent (C:\Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:113:22)
at MessagePayload.resolveData (C:\Bots\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessagePayload.js:128:26)
```

I've also tried to do a try catch method in my message command, but it also seems to fail. It's as if discord's entire system took full priority.

The reason why I need this error catching system to work is because this is a personal bot I use for my server. This isn't meant to be extremely well designed- and the catch error allows me to check up on the errors without the entire bot crashing.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Added snippets of the discord-return error for more clarity

Comment: If I'm right you weren't able to catch these kind of errors at all with the `error` event. You can catch the message errors as it returns a `Promise`. You simply add `.catch(console.log)` behind your `send` function.

Comment: While this can work, this is only function based. I run complex codes that include objects and whatnot, and I can't be putting .catch in every function I use to make sure my entire bot doesn't break. Back then with v12, I was able to catch the errors with no issues. What changed?